# How to report bug after hard crash?

Tags: bug-reporting

I just had a hard lock-up crash not even a <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> could solve. I've now rebooted and would like to report the bug with the saved logs.

What's the best way to report it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something you did triggered the freeze use [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) and trigger the freeze again. Apport will detect it automatically and you should be able to file a bug-report.

This is an excerpt from [Debugging System Crashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash)

- If your system crashes at random
  intervals, perform a [MemoryTest](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest) first
  before filing any bug reports or
  support requests
- If your system crashes when a
  particular action occurs, and this is
  repeatable every time, try the
  following steps:

  1. Try to reproduce the crash on a text
     console (Control+Alt+F1) if
     possible. If the crash occurs during
     startup, select the recovery mode
     option to disable the splash screen
  2. When the crash occurs, press
     Alt+SysRq+1 (one, not L) followed by
     Alt+SysRq+t. If using a text
     console, you should see a trace
     dumped to the screen. If the system
     is sufficiently alive, it will also
     be logged to /var/log/kern.log and
     visible in the output from dmesg.
     This information shows where the
     crash occurred, and should be
     included in any problem reports. If
     the output is not saved in any file,
     or the system is so bad off that you
     cannot retrieve it, you can either
     take a digital photo, or hand write
     the results. Almost all of the
     output is important (so please don't
     copy the one line you think is
     important, because context means
     everything).

Answer (score 0):

It's not even certain that there is any data to report. If there was, it would probably be in the old dmesg logs in /var/log. But since the kernel might not sync the filesystems if it crashes, the data could be lost. Did something you did cause it to crash?